# Achieving Tabular Pivot Type report in SQL

Tags: sql, sorting, union-all

I have the below code which I am trying to get the info of Population of City, County Total for those cities and State Total for all counties in the state. I was able to crack most of it except the State sorting or in genaral State sorting.

```
ORDER BY State, County, SortOrder, City, Population
```

Can someone help to check and recommend sorting changes to get the correct output? Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @JonasMetzler, I did that but didn't work as expected. It combined the County at the end instead of County after Cities of that county.

Comment: Maybe you could force those "State Total" rows to be sorted as last with a case when. Something like ORDER BY States, 
  CASE WHEN County = 'State Total:' THEN 'zz' ELSE County END, 
  SortOrder, City, Population

Comment: Good to know. But I'm not so happy with that solution, it's unclean. I'm too tired now for a better idea. In case no one answers, I would have a look again in the next days. At least you have a workaround so far ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an ideal opportunity to use *grouping sets*.

You can express all these queries as a single query with the following grouping sets:

```
select State, 
  Coalesce(County, 'State Total:')  County,
  Coalesce(City, case when County is null then '' end, 'County Total:') City,
  Sum(Population) Population
from t
group by grouping sets(
  (State, County, City), 
  (State, County), 
  (State)
)
order by State, 
  case when County = 'State Total:' then 1 end, 
  case when City = 'County Total:' then 1 end;
```

See a [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lB_6edfq)

And output:

[image]

Comment: Great! That's much cleaner and is what I was too tired to find yesterday ;)